# session expires to soon in php

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I want to extend a session time so that a session variable does not expire after 12 hours.

The problem is that after 24 minutes (default time for a session until it expires) of inactivity it still expires the session and hence gives me undefined indexes for those `SESSION` variables.

What else do I need to do in my code in order to be able to extend the sessions so that it does not expire on its own until 12 hours has passed:

The code below doesn't work is `ini_set()` is above `session_start();`

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',12*60*60);
    phpinfo();              
    session_start();

    // .... rest of code below

?>
```

The code below doesn't work is ini_set() is below session_start();

```
<?php
    phpinfo();              
    session_start();

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',12*60*60);

    // .... rest of code below

?>
```

In `phpinfo()`, it states this below for `gc_maxlifetime`:

```
                           Local Value  Master Value
session.gc_maxlifetime       43200        1440
session.cookie_lifetime      43200          0
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently only setting the time for garbage collection.  You should also set the cookie to expire in the browser with the [session.cookie_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) setting or `session_set_cookie_params()` function.

Comment: Ok I will test this, will the code be: `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',12*60*60);`?

Comment: it'll work, as long as you do the ini_set BEFORE you do anything sessino-related. PHP can't reach back in time to retroactively change a cookie expiry period if you ini_set AFTER the session's started.

Comment: Sorry bout that, I tested it when I came back but session still expires

Comment: @user1669425 It's likely that `ini_set()` is disabled on the server.

Comment: @TimPost ini_set() is not disabled. I asked the admin of the server. if I put the ini_sets() below or after session_start(), they still expire the session in 24 mintues rather than 24 hours. I have updated question so you can see what is happening